# JMeter - Perfmon user

Tags: jmeter

JMeter - Perfmon Metric Collector is used to monitor server resources but it's a gui functionality. So can I run test in non gui mode and then just use JMeter Perfmon Metric Collector for just monitoring remote server?

Answer (score 1):

There are following options:

1. Either configure [PerfMon Metrics Collector listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) to save results into a file

   [image]

   and run your test in non-GUI mode. Once your test finishes you will be able to open it in GUI mode and see the charts (or parse the output CSV file with other software)
2. Or run your main test in command-line non-GUI mode and launch a separate JMeter instance to observe the server-side metrics in the realtime as the test goes, you will need just a Sampler which does nothing like [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/) with response time matching your metrics collection interval

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, will it have any overhead? I mean will it have high overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. Refer to [Non-GUI Mode](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/#Non-GUI-Mode). You can set the required properties and once the test completes you can inspect the collected data by loading the file in the GUI application.

Comment: Thanks Shyam, will it have any overhead? I mean will it have high overhead?